# how to get all the values of a session after several httprequests in the same java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

```
import com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/ShowPersonServlet"})
public class ShowPersonServlet extends HttpServlet {
String key = "";
String lastName = "";
String firstName="";
HttpSession session;
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    key = request.getParameter("txt_Key");
    firstName = request.getParameter("txt_firstName");
    lastName = request.getParameter("txt_lastName");
    session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("key", key);
    session.setAttribute("firstName", firstName);
    session.setAttribute("lastName", lastName);
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet ShowPersonServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<table border=\"1\" width =\"400\" height=\"30\" >");
        out.println(" <tbody>");



Enumeration e = session.getAttributeNames();
while ( e.hasMoreElements() )
{
        String k = (String)e.nextElement();
        Object value = session.getAttribute(k);

        String k2 = (String)e.nextElement();
        Object value2 = session.getAttribute(k2);

        String k3 = (String)e.nextElement();
        Object value3 = session.getAttribute(k3);
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td >"+ value +"</td>");
        out.println("<td >"+ value2 +"</td>");
        out.println("<td >"+ value3 +"</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        }
        out.println(" </tbody>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("<form method=\"get\" action=\"ShowPersonServlet\">");
        out.println("<table width=\"1200\"  border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"2\">");
        out.println("<tbody>\n" +
"    <tr>\n" +
"      <td><label>Key=</label><br>\n" +
"      </td>\n" +
"      <td><input name=\"txt_Key\"><br>\n" +
"      </td>\n" +
"      <td>First Name=<br>\n" +
"      </td>\n" +
"      <td><input name=\"txt_firstName\"><br>\n" +
"      </td>\n" +
"      \n" +
"      <td >Last Name=</td>\n" +
"      <td><input name=\"txt_lastName\"><br>\n" +
"      </td>\n" +
"      <td><button type=\"submit\">Add</button><br>\n" +
"      </td>\n" +
"    </tr>\n" +
"  </tbody>\n" +
"</table>");

        out.println("</form>");
        out.println("</body>");

        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

}
```

I want to add (key firstname and lastname) to the above table each time i fill the textfields and press add by storing them in a session. But the problem is that each time i i add the new data replaces old ones (no new row created !!). Any help please.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class with the required attributes and then store the instance in the session with the key as attribute key or you may also create a List and store that List in session. Something as below.

```
class Person { 
   String key = "";
   String lastName = "";
   String firstName="";

   //create setter/getter for attributes
}
```

Then in the servlet

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setKey(key)
person.setFirstName(firstName);
person.setLastName(lastName);
```

I would recommend to maintain all the data in List and add the List to session.

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(person);

session.setAttribute("list", list);
```

And then loop through the list to get all the data. You need to modify the servlet code accordingly.

Comment: how to loop the list   for (String temp : list) {
  System.out.println(temp);
 }

Comment: why should i create a session if i didn't use it?

Comment: should i loop through the list or through session

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing in session variable, you must store user details in application context variable. A session is meant for each user. Hence list of all users must be application scoped rather than session scoped. Refer [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) api for more details